# Using a corollary of Tutte's theorem to prove a statement

Tags: graph-theory

I've been asked to prove that any graph $G$ which is $n$-connected, $n$-regular, and has even order has a one-factor.

A hint that we were given for proving this was a corollary to Tutte's theorem, which states that;

> If the graph of multigraph $G$ has an even number of vertices, then $G$ has no one-factor if and only if there is some $w$-set $W$ of vertices such that $G-W$ has at least $w+2$ odd components

However, I'm having a lot of trouble actually applying this to the question. I know that I have to use both the connectivity and regularity of the graph to say something about what components we get after removing a certain number of vertices, but I'm really just not confident in applying these two conditions.

I've tried to start a proof by contradiction to the above corollary, but I'm not sure if I'm even doing it correctly.

Firstly, we start with some graph $G$ of even order. We also note that, due to the connectivity of $G$, we must remove at least $n$ vertices to disconnect it into some number of components. So, this means that there exists some $n$-set $W$ of vertices such that $G-W$ has at least $n+2$ odd components.

At this point, I thought it was best to consider the cases in which $n$ was even, and $n$ was odd. If $n$ is even, then we need to remove an even number of vertices to disconnect $G$, which means that the order of $G-W$ would be even. But, at this stage, I'm not sure how to appeal to the connectivity of the graph to say anything of relevance. I'd like to say that, if we've got an even number of vertices, then we've got either an even number of even components, or an even number of odd components, but I'm just not sure.

In a similar way, if we delete an odd number of vertices from $G$, then we necessarily have an odd number of vertices left over, which would imply at least one odd component, but again, I'm not sure how to relate this back to the regularity of the graph, or the corollary itself.

If anyone could provide me with some insight into this, I'd be over the moon. This question is really stressing me out ;-;

Comment: I don't have an answer, but you appear to be going astray when you assume that, just because the graph is $n$-connected, the set of vertices which generates too many odd components must be of size $n$ -- it could be bigger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's perhaps easier to state Tutte's theorem as follows, which is how I mostly see it anyways.

**Tutte's Theorem:** Let $G(V,E)$ be a graph. Then $G$ has a perfect matching if and only if for every subset $W\subseteq V$ of vertices, the subgraph induced by $V\backslash W$ has at most $|W|$ odd components. $\square$

It's a simple exercise to prove that these two versions are equivalent; your version is just the negation of mine. Also note that there's no real need to consider multigraphs when finding perfect matchings as a multigraph will have a perfect matching if and only if its underlying simple graph has a perfect matching.

Now onto the proof of the corollary.

**Corollary:** Let $G(V,E)$ be a $n$-regular and $n$-connected graph. Then $G$ has a perfect matching.

**Proof:** Let $W\subseteq V$ be an arbitrary subset of the vertices of $G$. The graph induced by $V\backslash W$ contains even and odd components. Remove from $G$ (the original graph) all vertices belonging to the even components and collapse all vertices of each odd component to a single vertex $u_i$. Call the collection of such vertices $U$. Note that $|U|$ is precisely the number of odd components induced by $V\backslash W$.

Remove all multi-edges and loops from the resulting graph and remove all the edges internal to $W$. Note that what remains is a bipartite graph $\tilde{G}$ with vertex bipartition $(W,U)$.

Finally, note that $\deg(u_i) \ge n$ by the $n$-connectivity assumption while $\deg(w_i) \le n$ by the regularity assumption. Summing the degrees over the bipartition of $\tilde{G}$, we have
$$n|U|\le\sum_{u_i\in U}\deg(u_i)=\sum_{w_i\in W} \deg(w_i) \le n|W|$$
Therefore we conclude that $|U| \le |W|$. Since each vertex of $U$ represents an odd component, we conclude that the number of odd components induced by $V\backslash W$ is at most $|W|$. Since $W$ was arbitrary, this means that $G$ satisfies the hypotheses of Tutte's theorem and we have a perfect matching, as needed. $\square$

Comment: Thank you very much!! I still had a few questions, though. How does the bipartite graph come into existence?? I mean, couldn't the set $W$ be connected, which would ruin the bipartite graph??

Comment: @Jack Yes you are absolutely right. I should add the condition that the internal edges of $W$ should be removed. That will still preserve the condition $\deg(w_i) \le n$ which is what's required for the proof.

Comment: I also wanted to ask where the even order of the graph comes into the proof. Having drawn out a few examples, I can definitely see your proof is valid, and I'm also aware that a graph needs to have an even number of vertices to have a one-factor, but why doesn't this aspect come into the proof??

Comment: @Jack This assumption is hidden within Tutte's theorem. Notice that this condition has to hold for _any_ set of $W$. In particular, this must hold for when $W$ is the empty set of vertices. If the order of the graph is odd, then we have an odd component, which is larger than the size of the empty set $W$.

Comment: Aha, that makes a great deal of sense!! Thank you so much!! I really feel like I have a better grasp on Tutte's theorem, now.

As an aside, when we're considering a problem that involves usage of Tutte's theorem, is it worthwhile trying to break things into bipartite graphs?? A lot of my lecture material involved in connectivity and regularity has revolved around finding such graphs within other graphs, so I was just curious.

Comment: I also had one final question, which was to do with how the collapsing of the odd-components works. Say that, within $G-W$, you have an odd-component with 5 vertices. In the bipartite graph, which you defined in the proof, do we join the collapsed vertex to each of the vertices incident with those vertices in the odd-component??

Comment: @Jack It's difficult to say whether finding bipartite graphs will always be a good idea, but when faced with problems involving matches and coverings it's worth a shot. This is simply because we have so many powerful theorems to deal with bipartite graphs (i.e. Hall's, König's) that if we manage to reduce successfully to a bipartite graph, that's often a big step towards the solution. For your latter question, the procedure is exactly as you described; you join all vertices incident to the component to the collapsed vertex.